# error while creating custom view using XIB

Tags: ios, swift4.2, custom-view

I've created a custom view and interface using xib.

```
class CardStatus: UIView{

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let bundle = Bundle(for: CardStatus.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CardStatus", bundle: bundle)
        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { fatalError("Error loading \(self) from nib") }
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

}
```

xib looks like below:

[image]

in the storyboard, I've set the class as my custom one like below.

[image]

the error is like below:

[image]

its going in infinite loop.

I tried the below way also

```
class CardStatus: UIView{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)() {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let bundle = Bundle(for: CardStatus.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CardStatus", bundle: bundle)
        guard let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { fatalError("Error loading \(self) from nib") }
        addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

}
```

Comment: If you search for `swift load uiview from nib` you'll find lots and lots of examples, tutorials, discussions, etc. I'd suggest reading a few of those and see if you find a good way to do this.

Comment: I followed. Its the same code. I might did small mistake. I spent half day to understand this. Thought of getting help. Can you spot the issue?

Comment: Try following this tutorial (it's titled "Swift 3" but updated for Swift 5): https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960

Comment: I found the issue. I have not updated owner of the custom view. Thanks @DonMag